# Rules for redirecting multiple links

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Hi I'm migrating a site at the moment. I've got about 400 links I need to redirect. I know how to set up a redirect in the htaccess for each one but wold like to set up a rule. I want

www.example.com/2011/10/the-news-post

to redirect to

www.example.com/home/post/the-news-post

Is it possible to do this? And if so what does the code look like?

Thanks,

Gregor

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use "_" for redirection? I think using "-" will be better for your SEO

Comment: Indeed -- use keep using `-` -- it's recommended over `_`.

Comment: Yeh I'm using hyphens now - was an oversight! Ta.

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve the hyphens:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/([^/]+)$ [R=302,L]
```

In order to change the hyphens to underscores (which I also don't recommend):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+)-([^/]+)$ $1_$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/([^/]+)$ home/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Brief explanation:
The first rule matches any URL with the day/month followed by an article containing a hyphen.  It replaces the hyphen, then re-runs all the rewrite rules.  Once there are no hyphens left, it will pass through to the second rule, which rewrites the URL as home/articlename.

Demo: http://cerebraldonkey.com/mod_rewrite2/2011/5/some-article-containing-several-hyphens

Comment: Thanks moot. I've now replaced the underscores with hypens on all URLs (not sure why I thought it was a good idea to go with underscores... DOH!). So having done that all I need is this: RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/([^/]+)$ home/post/$1 [R=302,L] ?